# Getting certificate size with python script

Tags: python, for-loop, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

For a project I need to find the size of the certificate packet that is sent by server to client when setting up the ssl connection.

This happens over TCP and thus the packet can be split up over multiple segments. I have to do this on the top 100 Alexa sites. I am able to get the list of 100 sites and then running this code:

```
import ssl
import urllib
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import re


f = open("urls.txt", "r")
array = []

for line in f:
    line = line[:-1]
    array.append(line)

for a in array:
    str = ":443     | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ~/Desktop/thesis/certificates/" + a + ".cert"
    subprocess.getoutput('echo -n | openssl s_client -connect '+ a + str)
```

However this second for loop hangs after six iterations, so in my certificates folder there are only six certs.. Could someone tell me why this hangs and/or how to fix it? Thanks